# Where should the thread / task be started to see if you are still connected to a device (model or viewmodel)?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a C# / MVVM application that works with a device.  The application needs to constantly check to see it is connected / disconnected to this device.  I was given code that the Model (USB connection code project) starts a thread that will continuously check to see if the device is connected.  It will then use callbacks to the ViewModel to set the properties that are needed to be set.

But shouldn't the ViewModel start the thread and then call the appropriate methods in the "USB connection code project" to check this?

If I do keep the thread in the model then from reading other threads I probably should use INotifyPropertyChanged instead of delegates / callbacks....correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing code has it *exactly* right.

Checking a USB device has absolutely nothing to do with the view, or view logic; so it belongs in the model. Doing a delegate or event callback to tell the View Model to update its state is a perfectly reasonable notification mechanism.

Utilizing `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself is really painful, and not very semantically clear. I wouldn't change a thing about the described design.

Comment: Agreed, only implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` when you need to for the benefit of the data binding engine.  Better yet, implement it explicitly (hidden) to discourage people from handling it directly.  Stick to more explicit/meaningful events for communicating across layers of code.

Comment: Well it does have something to do with the View.  Because in a disconnected state means that certain buttons, checkboxes will be disabled and when connected that those would be enabled again.  One of the issues I was having was that one of the callback methods was being called again before it completed the previous time.  I can easily fix this though...  After thinking about what you guys said I think I agree with you guys.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @ashlar64 It doesn't have to do with the view, being disconnected changes a state variable that the view then represents.That state variable belongs in the view model. The code that sets the state variable is not view-related and so belongs in your model. Glad you got it working!